# Persuading webpack to use node_modules/@types

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to get to grips with using Typescript 2, Webpack and Angular 1.5, but when building Webpack keeps complaining that it:

Cannot resolve module '@types/angular' in C:\play\gt\src

I'm stumped. Been Googling this and messing about but am getting nowhere.

My app.ts looks like:

```
import * as angular from "@types/angular";
let app = angular.module ("GT.module", []);
```

My tsconfig looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots" : [
        "node_modules/@types"
      ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "include" : [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

...and lastly webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
        entry: './src/app.ts',
        output: {
            filename: './dist/app.js'
        },
        devtool: "source-map",
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js'],
            modulesDirectories: ["node_modules"]
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What is your directory tree looks like?
It should look like this:

```
node_modules/
   @types/
      angular/
src/
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
```

Then you don't need `"typeRoots" : ["node_modules/@types"]`

and `import * as angular from "@types/angular";` should became `import * as angular from "angular";`

The Typescript compiler 2.0 will know where to look to find the typings at the right places (ie: in `node_modules/@types`)

Comment: Thank you! That has solved it. The Typescript goal posts seem to keep moving and it's very difficult to find up to date articles.

Comment: Yeah I know, javascript ecosystem evolves pretty fast, try the official documentation, it is maintained pretty well. For example this link will wrap up webpack with typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

Answer (score 1):

`@types` are not modules you can import, they are typedefs for the compiler to reference.

The `@types/angular` package does not actually implement `.module` and your code will break (if it ever compiles).

You probably want to do something more like:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts" />
import * as angular from "angular";
let app = angular.module ("GT.module", []);
```

**But**, you typically won't even need the `reference`, as the compiler will automatically include typedefs from `@types/*` packages unless you tell it not to (by setting `types` or `typeRoot` in your `tsconfig.json`). This behavior was added in v2 and is fairly recent.